# How to Add a URL with Authentication to the AddHealthCheckEndpoint() method

Tags: asp.net, iis, blazor, blazor-server-side, windows-authentication

I have a blazor website, [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), hosted on IIS with windows authentication turned on. The site loads successfully and asks for authentication details as expected. The problem comes when I load the [www.example.com/healthchecks-ui](http://www.example.com/healthchecks-ui) page.
Since the UI page uses the [www.example.com/health](http://www.example.com/health) endpoint which is behind an authentication wall, the page loads with an unhealthy status as shown below:

[image]

When I turn off authentication and allow for anonymous connections on IIS the [www.example.com/healthchecks-ui](http://www.example.com/healthchecks-ui) page loads as expected:

[image]

This is how i set the healthcheck-ui settings in the startup.cs file:

```
            services.AddHealthChecksUI(opt =>
            {
                opt.UseApiEndpointHttpMessageHandler(sp =>
                {
                    return new HttpClientHandler
                    {
                        ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual,
                        ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (httpRequestMessage, cert, cetChain, policyErrors) => { return true; }
                    };
                });
                opt.SetEvaluationTimeInSeconds(5); //time in seconds between check    
                opt.MaximumHistoryEntriesPerEndpoint(60); //maximum history of checks    
                opt.SetApiMaxActiveRequests(1); //api requests concurrency    
                opt.AddHealthCheckEndpoint("Site Health", "www.example.com/health"); //map health check api    
            }).AddInMemoryStorage();
        }
```

and

```
                endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/health", new HealthCheckOptions()
                {
                    Predicate = _ => true,
                    ResponseWriter = UIResponseWriter.
                    WriteHealthCheckUIResponse
                });
                endpoints.MapHealthChecksUI();
```

Is there a way to account for authentication by adding some static credentials to be used? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Please configure the API like this: "iisSettings": { "windowsAuthentication": true, "anonymousAuthentication: false

Comment: Hi @BruceZhang i had already done this. I don't think this is the issue. Any other suggestion?